# Who ordered the bombers to attack?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Who ordered the bombers to attack the dreadnaught at the beginning of Star Wars: The Last Jedi? Was it Leia or Poe?

Comment: Poe. It was his plan, Leia only expressed concern about it, and then tried to get him to abort.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Poe says . . .

> "All Clear. Bring the bombs!"

. . . at which point the bombers start their attack run.

It's not entirely clear what his *standing* order from Leia were, other than to keep the dreadnought occupied while their transports left the surface.

As I've noted in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176992/why-is-poe-blamed-for-the-loss/176994#176994), Commander Poe appears to be the only one who can issue orders to his squadron (or else Leia would simply order them to withdraw) which means that **the responsibility for sending them into battle, in violation of Leia's clear orders, rests solely and firmly with him.**